# Access a variable's superclass's member in Java?

Tags: java, inner-classes, super

I have a collection of elements and want to separate the ability to add and remove elements, so I made two classes with those abilities. Then I also want the remover class to be able to take an instance of the adder class and transfer all of its elements to the remover's own collection. Looking at the example explains it a lot more easily:

```
public class Super {
    private Queue<E> elements;

    public class Thrower {
        public void throw(E e) {
            elements.add(e);
        }

    public class Catcher {
        public E catch() {
            return elements.poll();
        }

        public void transfer(Thrower t) {
            elements.drainTo(Super.t.elements);
        }
    }
}
```

However, `Super.t.elements` doesn't work. I figured it would since you can do stuff like `Super.this.elements`.

Is there anyway I can keep my separation of add/remove, while being able to implement the `transfer()` method?

Comment: What is B ? Is there any relation between E and B ?

Comment: Ahhhh sorry... I renamed them to be more descriptive and forgot that one... fixed it

Comment: Seems to me that it would be a better design to have to interfaces Adder and Remover and let Super implement those.

Comment: This code does not compile. Rename your methods.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Thrower` **have to extend** `Super`, and `elements` **should be protected** so `Thrower` can access `Super.elements`.

```
public class Super {
    protected Queue<E> elements;

    public class Thrower extends Super {
        public void thrower(E e) {//throw is a keyword
            elements.add(e);
        }

        public class Catcher {
            public E catcher() {//catch is a keyword
                return elements.poll();
            }

            public void transfer(Thrower t) {
                elements.remove(t.elements);//replaced the drainTo
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Super.t.elements` doesn't work I this case because `Super` does not have the property `t`, and even if it worked you are not using the `t` passed as argument.

Comment: Wouldn't this give Thrower/Catcher their own instances of elements? So it'd be accessing theirs instead of the super class'

Comment: Yes. That will be the case for Thower.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create those methods in the superclass too.
Protected methods will allow you to restrict the use of those to extending classes.

Although I don't really see the point in separating the add and the remove method in different classes - If you want "Classes" which only have the Add or Remove methods you could just create two Interfaces for that and implement both with your current superclass.

Here's a quick example:

```
public interface Adder<E> {
  void add(E element);
}
```

and

```
public interface Remover<E> {
  void remove(E element);
}
```

And your superclass would look like this:

```
public class YourClass implements Adder, Remover {

  private Queue<E> elements;

  public void add(E element) {
    elements.add(element);
  }

  public void remove(E element) {
    elements.remove(element);
  }
}
```

When you want to provide "instances" that only can remove or add but use the same list use this:

```
YourClass myInstance = new YourClass(); //Doesn't matter just retrieve your instance
Adder adder = (Adder) myInstance; //Only has "#add" method
Remover remover = (Remover) myInstance; //Only has "#remove" method
```

As for your transfer method I'm not exactly sure what you want to do there but I think you can implement it yourself should you decide to use this approach.